# Element blocking using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a table with two td and a div in first td and I have included a page in one div I want the div to be fade until it finished loading I want to do it using jquery. Remember I want only the div to be disabled not the other td. Any help would be appreciated

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width=35px height="100%" >
<div id="blur">
<img src="">
</div>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want only the div code to blocked, or an ajax event until it finishes thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of "I want" in your question; did you try anything at all before asking? Do you have a first-attempt to show us, that we could help with?

Comment: this is my requirement  see i  have a accordion panel (jsf/primefcaes) inside it a div and in  the div i have included a page when i click the accordion panel page will start loading . iwant accordion panel background to be faded until it loads completly .or same in case of ajax events does jquery has any solution for this

Comment: But my point is (or 'was'): did you try to implement a solution yourself, before asking? If you could show us your failed/broken attempt it becomes much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set it to display:none, and on page load, displaying it ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width=35px height="100%" >
            <div id="blur" style="display:none">
                <img src="">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then

```
$(function(){$('#blur').show()});
```

(but you're not forced to do it on page load, you can do it when you want: ajax callback, various events...)

Comment: no i want to blur it when page load happens ,for eg when a menu click happens a particular page will get loaded in the div i want the div to be blured until the page downloadd completly